# Place document styles on the right of the document in Microsoft Word for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

On my PC, I can place (or doc) the MS Word styles to the right of the document/screen. Is this possible on Word 2011 for OS-X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a button for it next to the quick styles bar, see the following screenshot.

[image]

(click for larger image)

The same can be found in `View -> Toolbox -> Styles`.

Comment: I figured it would be hiding in plain site. Thanks.